# Start playing a loaded audio file in the middle with Chrome webkitAudioContext?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I'm working with the Chrome web audio API and webkitAudioContext to play loops. I have several loops that I'm crossfading in between similar to the [Digital DJ](http://chromium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/samples/audio/dj.html) example on chromium blog.

In their example they are switching the samples when the loop hits the end of a cycle and then they start playing the next loaded loop. I want to start the new loop instantly and crossfade in between but I have yet to find an example on how to start play a new audio file in the middle and not only from start.

I've looked through the [W3C Web Audio API](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html) and the noteOn parameter you send in is only a time coded related to the context currentTime attribute when the audio should start playing. It always start playing from the beginning of the sample.

Is there more documentation or something I have overlooked how to start playing an audio file 2seconds in to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the `noteGrainOn` method of your `AudioBufferSourceNode`. That method takes an offset and a duration.

Comment: I think I've tried that one but ran in to another problem, I will double check when I get back home in 2 days. The problem I ran in to was when I was looping the sound because the loop starts at the offset in noteGrainOn and I wanted it to start from the beginning of that particular sound again.

Comment: yeah, that makes sense, i wonder if you create two buffer source nodes, and have the grain one non-looping, and schedule the looping player to start at the end of the grain?

Comment: That would probably work good. Too bad it's not built in to repeat from the start of the sound.